# Calling PHP From C

Tags: php, c, embed

I am trying to write an application that will use PHP as a scripting language.  The application is a CGI handler, and I want to be able to call PHP pages from it.

I am looking for code that will let me initialize PHP inside the C program and then pass it either a buffer containing the php code, or a filename, for it to parse.  I want to take the output from that and be able to run it through a function in the CGI program.

Comment: A Note, I can not use the system() call, as I wish to provide PHP with access to variables used inside of the C program.  There is another language that is also being used, and I need to be able to share variables between them.  I have the bridge set up that will let C access the variables from the other language, I just need to figure out how to embed the php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book [Extending and Embedding PHP](http://blog.libssh2.org/index.php?/archives/24-Extending-and-Embedding-PHP.html) by Sara Golemon *([amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232704X))* has a chapter about embedding PHP in a C programm, which might interest you.

If you want a preview, from what I remember, some pages are avaible on Google books, for instance.

Here's a quick quote *(from the beginning of chapter 20.)* :

> In addition to loading external
>   scripts, as you saw in the last
>   chapter, your PHP embedding
>   application can also execute smaller
>   snippets of arbitrary code using the
>   underlying function that implements
>   the familiar userspace `eval()`
>   command.

Comment: I have not put into practice what's written in it, but it's an interesting read anyway :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would check out how they've implemented the php command line binary. It seems the main function is in [php_cli.c](http://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/sapi/cli/)

And it calls `php_execute_scrip` and a bunch of other functions which looks promising.

Comment: Let's see how this and `apt install php-all-dev php-dev libphp-embed` would help. `.h` headers are here: `apt-file list php7.2-dev` and the `.so` file is here: `apt-file list libphp7.2-embed`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [PHPEmbed](http://developers.facebook.com/phpembed/) library. It's for C++, rather than C, but it might still work for you, depending on the project requirements.

Comment: Good link.  It wont work for me, but I can use it to see how to code what I need.  Thank you.

Comment: That link is dead.

Comment: Probably this one now: https://github.com/facebookarchive/phpembed