# Is it possible access php variables from dart?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, dart

Edit: The PHP and Dart script will run on client-side.

I will run a php script on my page load. Then i would like to access the php functions within dart scope. Is it possible or should i migrate everything to dart?

To be more specific;

- I am tring to develop a facebook application (with facebook php sdk),
- I have written several 'Hello, World!' web applications,
- and that is all experience i got for now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And dear sir/madam, may i ask the reason for -1. So that, i can fix the question.

Comment: Do you want to use dart on server side or on client side ?

Comment: Client-side. I am appending this info to question, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. There is no clean way to communicate between Dart and PHP. With client-side Dart, you have the normal problem of client-side vs server-side scripting. With server-side Dart, as far as I can tell (researching with google), there is no interoperability between the two.

## Client-side vs Server-side Scripting

In web development, there are two main classes of programming languages: server-side and client-side. Server-side languages are run on the web server and determine the response that the web server sends to reply to the HTTP request. Client-side languages are run on the client (read, browser) and manipulate the DOM, etc in the browser.

Calling server-side code from client-side code would be like running a command on your friends computer from your computer without ssh. Directly calling a server-side function from a client-side language (`function my_client_func() { my_server_func(); }`) is impossible.

### Workarounds

There are a number of ways to achieve this functionality. Two are AJAX and WebSockets.

[AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) allows you to make HTTP requests asynchronously and act on the data when it arrives. You could create a mechanism to retrieve data from the server via special web pages, or something similar. You could make a page called `facebook.com/apps/yourapp/function.php` and call it with parameters like `name=myFuncitonName&var1=something&var2=else`, etc (`function.php?name=myFunction...`).

[WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) allows you to create a full-duplex TCP-esque. You could create a PHP WebSocket server that would call functions based on received WebSocket messages, though this could create a security hole.

## Server-side Language Interoperability

Some server-side languages provide mechanisms to interoperate with other such languages. Dart does not seem to provide a mechanism to call PHP code.

### Workarounds

Dart does provide a mechanism to run processes in the form of the Process class. You could use the Process class to call the PHP interpreter.

Dart does provide interoperablility with C. Using [Native Extensions](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/), Dart code can call C functions. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902409/calling-php-from-c) question, C code can call PHP functions.

Comment: Thanks, i imagined it would be possible like "... <?php echo 'PHP will do the trick' ?> ...". My goal was to move all the load to client-side. I guess, i have to try your solution.

Comment: @GökhanBarışAker That can work, but it gets messy and is a workaround. I added some more information at the end.

Comment: Just for clarification, Dart can work on both the server and client side.

Comment: @scribeGriff I added what information I could find on Dart/PHP server-side interoperation.